# Splitting string by brackets and pushing into array

Tags: jquery

I have the following string

```
"[01][23.81][New]"
```

I am trying to break up the string by retrieving the values between the brackets and placing them into an array so that it looks something like the following

```
array({
   "id"        : 01,
   "price"     : 23.81,
   "condition" : "New"
});
```

**Here is what I have so far...**

```
var arr = new Array();
$("input:checkbox.addItm:checked").each(function(){
    //str.split('[');
    arr.push({
       "id": $(this).val()
    });
});
```

I want to know what is the best way to split the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression instead:

```
var m = "[01][23.81][New]".match(/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]/);
arr.push({
  id: m[1], // 01
  price: m[2], // 23.81
  condition: m[3]  // New
});
```